# how to test a web site to see how much punishment it can take before crashing?

Tags: testing, web, performance-testing, denial-of-service

My boss wants me to test our web application to demonstrate how much traffic the web site can handle.

The app is a JSF/JPA/Oracle application, everything is running on one rack mounted server at a local hosting company's data centre.

The truth is, we don't know how much traffic it can handle before it gets unresponsive or shuts down altogether.

What would be a good way to pound on the web app from the internet, simulating tonnes of traffic?  I was thinking of setting up a number of different Amazon EC2 virtual machines and getting them to pretend to be web visitors, but is there some kind of software I can run on these machines so they behave like lots of web visitors?

Also, it doesn't have to be free, I'd be willing to apy for a solution or a tool.

Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks, Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, mate:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/programs/ab.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting up Selenium-Grid to run tests in parallel. This will simulate actual user actions on the application and in-turn can stress the app server. You can install a performance monitoring utility on the server to monitor the load generated.

Or you could also use J Meter to simulate multiple users accessing your application. You can talk to your network admin team to route this traffic via internet instead of your local internet.